# Stop vim from deleting Swap file

Tags: vim

I like Vim's swap file system and I want to be prepared for the case I forget to :w, reusing this system.
I think it's possible if I can change when Vim deletes the swap file, but I could not find the way firstly to stop Vim from deleting it.
Do you know how to do it? or any alternative?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See `:help swap-files`.